# Complex Inheritance in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-4

That's my first post here. Thanks in advance everyone that collaborates with me.

I'm working on a new MER, this is a piece of the it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt5Mz.png.

[image]

In the linked MER, i'm using **Table per Hierarchy** on entities: Person, Company and Individual. Driver entity is on based on **Table per Type**.

My big problem is that a **Driver** can be **Individual** or **Company**.

Both **Individual** or **Company** inherites from **Person** that holds **common fields** from both entities.

There is a way to make the **Driver** entity flexible to be an **Individual** or a **Company**, using the **Table per Type** on **Driver** entity?

Thanks you all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change the design to say that a 'Driver' is 'associated' (0..1) rather than inherited from a Person.  Basically making 'driver' an optional entity of person then both individual or company will inherit this.

Comment: When I design I just thought in **object oriented model**. Do you think that as a class the **Driver** is correct?

Comment: @gblmarquez Are all Companies drivers?  Are all Individuals drivers?  If the answer to both is yes, then why not make companies and individuals derived from 'driver' rather than person?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change it so that Driver HAS A Person instead of Driver IS A Person.  i.e. you have a separate Driver class and it has a field on it called Person and that 'Person' is either an individual or a company.

OR you should move the DriverNumber field to the Person class so that a Person (Individual or Company) can be a 'Driver' if they happen to have a driver number.

Comment: I can't **add** to **Person** the field **DriverNumber** because there will be another entities like **Driver**. Maybe **Customer** is the first in my mind. When I design I just thought in **object oriented model**. Do you think that as a class the **Driver** is correct?

Comment: Driver shouldn't inherit from Person: in the real world any person can become a Driver at any time or they can stop being a driver but in OO an object can't change class.

Making 'Driver' a separate class with a 1:0 association to Person is the right thing to do because it models the fact that a Person can be a driver or can stop being a driver at any time.

(I would also rename Person to Entity since a company isn't really a 'Person').